# what is missing in my java regex?

Tags: java, regex

I want to fetch

`http://d1oiazdc2hzjcz.cloudfront.net/promotions/precious/2x/p_608_o_6288_precious_image_1419866866.png`

from

`url(http://d1oiazdc2hzjcz.cloudfront.net/promotions/precious/2x/p_608_o_6288_precious_image_1419866866.png)`

I have tried this code:

```
String a = "";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("url(.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(imgpath);

if (matcher.find()) {
    a = (matcher.group(1));
}

return a;
```

but `a == (http://d1oiazdc2hzjcz.cloudfront.net/promotions/precious/2x/p_639_o_4746_precious_image_1419867529.png)`

how can I fine tune it?

Comment: You don't need a regex here.. Use `substring`.

Comment: I don't see any `'` or `;` or `"` or `>`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I edit and yet no match

Comment: I still don't see any `'` in the sample string you're showing us.

Comment: @user1065869 You still have `'`, remove them and you'll be OK. But as I said earlier, `substring` should be fine here.

Comment: thanks, now i get too long result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Why use a regular expression to begin with?

Given

```
final String s = "url(http://d1oiazdc2hzjcz.cloudfront.net/promotions/precious/2x/p_608_o_6288_precious_image_1419866866.png)";
```

If the string is always the same format a simple `substring(4,s.length()-1)` would be better.

#### That said, if you insist on a regular expression:

You have to escape the `(` with `\(` so in Java ( you have to escape the `\` ) it would be `\\(` same with the `)`.

Then you can get the grouping with `url\\((.+)\\)`, [test it here](https://regex101.com/r/iZ4eU4/1)!

*Learn to use RegEx101.com before coming here, it will point out errors like this immediately.*

Answer (score 1):

As you already seem to know `(` and )` represents groups which means that in regex

```
url(.*)
```

`(.*)` will place everything after `url` in group 1, which in case of

`url(http://d1oiazdc2hzjcz.cloudfront.net/promotions/precious/2x/p_608_o_6288_precious_image_1419866866.png)`

will be

`(http://d1oiazdc2hzjcz.cloudfront.net/promotions/precious/2x/p_608_o_6288_precious_image_1419866866.png)`

If you want to exclude `(` and `)` from match you need to add their literals to regex, which means you need to escape them. There are many things to do it, like adding `\` before each of them, or surrounding them with `[` `]`.

Other problem with your regex is that `.*` finds maximal potential match but since `.` represents any character (except line separators) it can also include `(` and `)`. To solve this problem you can make `*` quantifier reluctant by adding `?` after it so your final regex can be written as string

```
"url\\((.*?)\\)"
---------------
url
\\(    - ( literal
(.*?)  - group 1
\\)    - ) literal
```

or you can use instead of `.` character class which will accept all characters except `)` like

```
"url\\(([^)]*)\\)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
url\((.*?)\)
```

The outermost parentheses are escaped so they will be matched literally.  The inner parentheses are for capturing a group.  The question mark after the .* is to make the match lazy, so the first closing parenthesis found will end the group.

Note that to use this regex in Java, you'll have to additionally escape the backslashes in order to express the above regex as a string literal:

```
String regex = "url\\((.*?)\\)";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `()` to match the parenthesis in the string, and then add another set of `()` around the part you want to pull out in group 1, the actual url. I also changed the part inside the parenthesis to `[^)]*`, which will match everything until it finds a `)`. See below:

```
url\(([^)]*)\)
```